# How to set push key when pushing to firebase database?

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

When I write data to firebase database from both frontend(Angular 4) and backend(firebase functions), there is a push key generated by firebase. With this key, I cannot access data in the future because the key is unique. I am wondering is any way I can set the key myself or I can access the data without knowing the key?

Here is my code from frontend:

```
this.db.list(`${this.basePath}/`).push(upload);
```

Here is my code from backend:

```
admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: original}).then(function (snapshot) {
res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref);});
```

All data I pushed will be under path/pushID/data

[image: simple image]

I cannot access data without knowing the pushID. 
The best case I want is path/my own pushID/data

Thanks so much for help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to loop through all messages:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("messages");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(message) {
    console.log(message.key+": "+message.val().original);
  });
});
```

If you want to find specific messages, use a query:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("messages");
var query = ref.orderByChild("original").equalTo("aaaa");
query.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(message) {
    console.log(message.key+": "+message.val().original);
  });
});
```

For much more on this, read the Firebase documentation on [reading lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events), [sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data), and take the [Firebase codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/).

Comment: If you're using queries you'll also want to add a `".indexOn"` rule to your database to help the database efficiently get you the data you need. More about rules and indexing here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data

Answer (score 1):

The keys should be unique in any way. You can `set` your own key like this instead of `push`

```
admin.database().ref('/messages/'+ yourUniqueId).set({original: original}).then(function (snapshot) {
 res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref);});
```

`yourUniqueId` can be `auth uid` or `email` of user, like something unique.